# Windows Builder Can't Adjust Sizes

Tags: java, windows, swing, builder

so I have adding some components and layouts, but the problem is I cant resize it.
Whenever I put a JLabel, it automatically goes to the far left. I want to position the size by clicking on the top-left corner, but it doesnt drag for some reason. And dragging the JLabel to another position doesnt work as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Show some code and/or maybe a link to a screenshot.

Comment: Which GUI Buider are you using? NetBeans?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of how the GUI should appear at default size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* Put the GUI builder aside until you understand how to use (and combine) layout managers.  Until you do, the designer will be your boss rather than the other way around.